# Parametric or Template test by Ethernet Compliance Test

Tags: ethernet, test, board, compliance

[image]

I am trying to design this part of TC6 from Ethernet test fixture board. As I dont need rest part of the parts for my test. Can someone tell me what are the loads are? Here three different loads can be switched using jumper. Moreover I am not getting the idea of connecting both RJ45 connectors actually how they are connected.

https://download.tek.com/manual/TDSET3.pdf

Comment: Need a datasheet for this